# Videogame Streaming with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming

I'd like to develop a streaming videogame application. Sort of what you can do with Nvidia SHIELD: stream games from a powerful PC to any web browser.

I'm just wondering if there would be any chance to accomplish that using node.js (I just know the basics of it). So that I could run a game in my desktop gaming pc and I can catch the controller events and watch the stream of the gameplay at the web browser of my old laptop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In theory this could be accomplished using something [like this](http://granular.cs.umu.se/browserphysics/?p=2287) though I doubt that you will get good enough performance to play any games well with it.

The Nvidia Shield uses [the GPU to transcode the current videostream to h264](http://shield.nvidia.com/faq/) for sending it efficiently over the network, you won't get that kind of support within a node.js application.

Comment: The whole CS-subdomain seems to be unavailable right now but since it's a large university page I hope it will be back soon. Meanwhile you can find a gist of the code here https://gist.github.com/bellbind/6724836